# In android 5.0, "excludeFromRecents = true" does not work any more

Tags: android, android-activity

I set `excludeFromRecents="true"` in the Activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. But it does not work anymore on API-21.

Here is the reproduce steps:

1. Make sure no recent tasks.
2. Start an activity whose `excludeFromRecents` is true.
3. Check recent task, and it is there.

It seems to me like an android 5.0's bug. Anyone knows the solution or workaround?

Comment: I thought this is a big bug. But don't know why there is no discussion about this.

Comment: Fortunately in Android 5.2, that is API-22, the issue has been fixed.